# Design HTML Data-Content Video So It's Responsive

Tags: html, css, media, responsive

I'm trying to make the following video responsive

```
    <abccs:avplayer data-contentid="123456789" data-width="800" data-alignment="center" data-autoplay="false" data-pr="0" data-adtagsuffix=";player=embedded" style="width: 800px; height: 450px;" class="center"></abccs:avplayer>
```

I originally created three separate divs and assigned them each a class then used display: none to hide them for certain screen sizes. However, having so many embeds on the page was causing the videos not to load. Any ideas on how to get it responsive? I'm not sure exactly what to target since it's not a typical YouTube or Vimeo link.

My original code was this:

```
    <div class="media-full">
<div class="media-container">
    <abccs:avplayer data-contentid="123456789" data-width="800" data-alignment="center" data-autoplay="false" data-pr="0" data-adtagsuffix=";player=embedded" style="width: 800px; height: 450px;" class="center"></abccs:avplayer>
</div>
```

```
    <div class="media-med">
<div class="media-container">
    <abccs:avplayer data-contentid="123456789" data-width="480" data-alignment="center" data-autoplay="false" data-pr="0" data-adtagsuffix=";player=embedded" style="width: 480px; height: 270px;" class="center"></abccs:avplayer>
</div>
```

```
    <div class="media-sm">
<div class="media-container">
    <abccs:avplayer data-contentid="123456789" data-width="320" data-alignment="center" data-autoplay="false" data-pr="0" data-adtagsuffix=";player=embedded" style="width: 320px; height: 150px;" class="center"></abccs:avplayer>
</div>
```

```
    .media-container {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;}

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
.media-sm, .media-med {
    display:none;
}}

    @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.media-sm, .media-full {
    display:none;
}}

    @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
.media-med, .media-full {
    display:none;
}}
```

However, I can no longer use this method. Although it worked fine, three embeds per video caused slow load time.

Comment: please give more details. what are the 3 divs?

Comment: Updated above @GabrielChiHongLee